# Jersey and JAX RS not returning headers in Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I have written this Rest Request in order to get some headers. But its behaving a little bit strange than what I expected.

Below is my Rest Code.

```
  import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

 @RestController
 public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping("/api")

    public Response getHeadersAndBody() {
      return Response.ok().header("myname", "args").build();
  }
  }
```

I am expecting headers to come separately, Not as a part of the body, but here they are coming as a part of the body.

Can Someone explain what I am doing wrong here.

Below is my pom.xml, dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
   <version>2.27</version>
   </dependency>
```

Below is the Response.

[image]

Comment: how are you able to get the body when it is not at all set in the response? can you try `.entity("")` after setting the header?

Comment: Already tried, Response body contains the entity and entity type also , "entity": "Response Body",
"entityType": "java.lang.String",

Comment: What HTTP client is that?

Comment: Restlet client, but doesn’t matter I have tried on postman also.

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate, you are not using JAX-RS/Jersey; you are using Spring MVC. If you want to use Jersey, then look for a tutorial on Jersey.